# Changing lines in specific file types in subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x, subdirectory, readline, file-type

I am trying to create a script that will search through a user input file path and open all the .cix file type and replace line 27.

What I have so far works on individual folders opening the files within one at a time and modifying the desired line. But if I try to use it on a folder with subfolders it's not working. It is opening and saving the file but it's not changing the line and I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x75')
root.title('Labels Off')

dirLabel = Label(root, text='Directory Path:').pack()
e = Entry(root, width='50')
e.pack()

os.listdir(path='.')

def replace(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(filename)
    f.close()
    if 'ENABLELABEL=1' in lines[27]:
        lines[27] = '   ENABLELABEL=0\n'
    elif 'ENABLELABEL=0' in lines[27]:
        lines[27] = '   ENABLELABEL=1\n'
    else:
        print('err')

    f = open(filename, 'w')
    f.write(''.join(lines))
    f.close()

def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    # create a list of file and sub directories 
    # names in the given directory 
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    # Iterate over all the entries
    for entry in listOfFile:
        # Create full path
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        # If entry is a directory then get the list of files in this directory 
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)

    counter = 0
    for file in allFiles:
        if file.endswith('.cix'):
            replace(file)
        else:
            allFiles.pop(counter)
        counter += 1

    return allFiles

def run():
    dirName = e.get()
    getListOfFiles(dirName)
    e.delete(0, END)

submit = Button(root, text='Run', command=run).pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: How do you know that it's opening and saving the file, if it doesn't change the line?

Comment: Note that `lines[27]` is the 28th line, not the 27th line (`lines[0]` being the first line).

Comment: Yes i am aware that python starts with 0. Thank you though. As for your other question. I can see that it is being opened and saved because the modified date in the file explorer is changing.

Comment: Do you see the `print(filename)` output? And the `err` output?

Comment: Yes i do...I put those in while testing trying to figure out whats was going wrong.

***EDIT
OH WAIIT... you meant do i see it in the output right? I do see filename in the output but not error.

Comment: And do you see the same filename more than once?

Comment: No i only see it once.

Comment: Then it appears the code replacing the lines is executed. How do you know that the lines were not replaced?

Comment: UPDATE: OK The very first one only appears once but all the others are showing up twice. So i now understand the problem but what is causing it. I know how to fix it now i just need to remove duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210252/discussion-between-ihamilton-and-mkrieger1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i don't know exactly what was wrong with my previous method of creating a file list but something wasn't working right. After trying for a while i replaced my previous method with this and it now works perfectly,

```
def getListOfFiles(dirName):

    allFiles = []
    for r, d, f, in os.walk(dirName):
        for file in f:
            if '.cix' in file:
                allFiles.append(os.path.join(r, file))


    for file in allFiles:
        replace(file)

    return allFiles
```

Comment: The difference is the same as what I described in my answer: It separates getting a list of files from calling `replace`. `os.walk` just also replaces the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

`getListOfFiles` returns a list of files for the current directory and all subdirectories *and also* calls `replace` on every `.cix` file in this list.

But it does this recursively, so for every `.cix` file that is in a subdirectory one level deeper, `replace` was already called.

Since `replace` basically toggles a line between `ENABLELABEL=1` and `ENABLELABLE=0`, for every `.cix` file that is in a subdirectory that is at an *odd* number of levels below the root directory, there is effectively no change.

The solution is to *first* get a complete a list of files and *then* call `replace` for each `.cix` file:

```
def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    # create a list of file and sub directories 
    # names in the given directory 
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    # Iterate over all the entries
    for entry in listOfFile:
        # Create full path
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        # If entry is a directory then get the list of files in this directory 
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)

    # no replace(file) here

    return allFiles

def run():
    dirName = e.get()
    allFiles = getListOfFiles(dirName)

    # instead, do it here
    for file in allFiles:
        if file.endswith('.cix'):
            replace(file)

    e.delete(0, END)
```

(I also didn't understand what you were trying to achieve with `counter`. I just omitted it.)